# Production config Webpack build for a Rust, WebAssembly app to apache2 server

Tags: apache, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm

I have a Rust, Web assembly `wasm` app I need to deploy to an apache server. When upload the build, it doesn't run the software, it just shows a list of the files.

The build files look like this:

```
build
  -0.bootstrap.js
  -bootstap.js
  -gfdgjkljlkjjiojohio.module.wasm
```

my webpack config looks like

const path = require('path');

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./bootstrap.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bootstrap.js",
  },
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    //host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 8080,
  }
};
```

Where boostrap.js imports the main index.js file

```
// A dependency graph that contains any wasm must all be imported
// asynchronously. This `bootstrap.js` file does the single async import, so
// that no one else needs to worry about it again.
import("./index.js")
  .catch(e => console.error("Error importing `index.js`:", e));
```

But when I deploy to my apache server, to my domain, I don't get the software running.

Why isn't it running?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) and change my webpack config to this

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './bootstrap.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    }),
  ]
}
```